# How does $f_0(z(0))' < 0 \Rightarrow f_0(z(t)) \lt f_0(x)$?

Tags: proof-explanation, convex-optimization

From Convex optimization by Boyd and Vanderberghe:

In the red box in the proof below:

How does the fact that the derivative of $f_0(z(t))$ at $t=0$ show that $f_0(z(t)) \lt f_0(x)$?

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function $g(t) = f_0(z(t))$. It is given that
$$
 g'(0) = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{g(t) - g(0)}{t-0}
$$
exists and is negative. From the definition of the limit it follows that
there is a $\delta > 0$ such that
$$
\frac{g(t) - g(0)}{t-0} < \frac 12 g'(0)
$$
for $|t| < \delta$. Consequently, for $0 < t < \delta$, 
$$
g(t) < g(0) +  \frac t2 g'(0) < g(0) \, .
$$

Comment: How does it follow that for small $t$ we have $g(t) - g(0) \lt 0$?  Where is $t$ sufficient?

Comment: And why can you be sure that it's not $0$ or positive for small positive $t$?

Comment: @OliverG: I have added more details.